# how can i able to send pdf or any doc file on database using post form-data in ionic 3?

Tags: json, html, typescript, ionic3

How can i post form data with file on database in ionic 3?

I have already tried following  solution:

my service.ts file:

```
addFilesApi(data): Observable<any> {
 console.log("addFilesApi service data", data);

 let headers = new Headers({ "enctype": "multipart/form-data" });

 var form_data = new FormData();
 for (var key in data) {
  console.log("addFilesApi key", key);
  form_data.append(key, data[key]);
   console.log("addFilesApi form_data", form_data);
 }

return this.http.post(apiUrl + 'FilesModule/addFile', form_data, { headers: headers })
  .map((response) => {
    console.log("addFilesApi response", response.json());
    return response.json();
  })
  // .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

my home.ts file:

```
addFilesforRNAppz(event) {

 let eventObj: MSInputMethodContext = <MSInputMethodContext>event;
 let target: HTMLInputElement = <HTMLInputElement>eventObj.target;
 let files = target.files;

 let file = files[0];
 let fileObj = {
      User_Id: this.userId,
      sessionId: this.sessionId,
      File_Name: file,
      File_Description: "new file created",
      Categories_Id: 1
    }

 this.serviceProvider.addFilesApi(fileObj).subscribe((result) => {
      // this.loader.hide();
      console.log("result addFilesApi" +JSON.stringify(result));
      // this.notes = result["data"];
      if(result['success'] == 4) {
        this.errorMessage = '';
        let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
          subTitle: result["message"],
          buttons: [
            {
              text: 'OK',
              handler: () => {
                console.log('ok clicked');
                this.navCtrl.push("SigninPage");
              }
            }
          ]
        });
        alert.present();
      } else if(result['success'] == 1) {
        this.errorMessage = '';
        this.getFilesFromDatabase();
      } else if(result['success'] == 2) {
        this.errorMessage = result['message'];
      } else {

      }

    }, (err) => {
      // this.loader.hide();
      console.log("err addFilesApi" +JSON.stringify(err));
      // Error log
    });

}
```

my home.html file:

I can send image to server, but couldn't post file in database. I have to save any type of file in mysql database with form data parameter.

How it is possible, If you have any solution, please share here as soon as possible.